# Error Handling: Cannot find specific error in scope

Tags: ios, swift, macos, error-handling, scope

I am trying to catch a specific error, but it is not in scope. Files are visible to each other

**MyMath.swift**

```
import Foundation

public func quadraticEquation(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) throws -> Array<Double> {

enum AllError: Error {
    case ABCError(String)
    case ZeroError(String)
}

guard a != 0 else {throw AllError.ZeroError("Bad Validate")}
```

**main.swift**

```
import Foundation
import MyMath

func main() -> Int32{
    do{
        try print(MyMath.quadraticEquation(a: 0, b: -6, c: 9))
    }catch AllError.ZeroError{     //Cannot find 'AllError' in scope
        print(AllError.ZeroError)
    }
}
exit(main())
```

Comment: try declaring it as public. Make sure to move it out of your method.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you! I thought the method should be inside a function